# .NET application times out or does not connect when invoking a stored procedure accesses Oracle linked server

Tags: oracle, sql-server-2005, linked-list, odbc

This .NET application used to work.  When it did we were using the Oracle ODBC 9i.  We moved to 10 g did not work anymore.  Now at 11g stills does not work.  I have set SQL Command Timeouts all over the place.  I have set the connection timeout and the query timeout in the linked server properties to 120.  I can run the proc from SQL Server Management studio and it works.  It just does not work within my .NEt application anymore.  Should I create a second connection string( to linked server) in the .NET app?  We are at SQL Server 2005. Any Ideas??

Answer (score 0):

Has your server you're connecting to moved, or are there now firewalls in place between the two servers?

I would check connectivity between the two first.
Try connecting to the oracle server using telnet on port 1521.

Alternatively, try using ODAC and checking your tnsnames.ora is configured correctly.
(It depends what provider you're using though.)